# Add video in aframe dynamically

Tags: aframe

My requirement is to simply play a video (url in json file) on a plane in aframe. I have created video entity in my html as follows

```
<a-video id="video_1" position="0 0 2" geometry="width:2.4;height:1.4"></a-video>
```

Inside my register component i have added the src file to video as below

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('myComp', {
    schema: {
        file: {type: 'asset', default: 'assets/data/file1.json'},
        var: {type: 'number', default: 0}
    },
    init: function () {
    },
    update: function () {
        var data = this.data;
        var scene = this.el.sceneEl;
        var screen = scene.querySelector('#video_' + data.var);
        load(data.file, function (response) {
            var products = response.mydata;
            screen.setAttribute('src',products[data.var].videoUrl);
        });
        this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            console.log("mouseenter",screen.getAttribute('src'));
        });
    }
});
```

My console log is displayed with path mentioned in the json file

```
"mouseenter assets/img/movies/videos/video1.mp4"
```

In network tab, i could see my file got fetched with type media and status 200. But still i am getting error

```
components:texture:warn `$s` is not a valid video +41ms assets/img/movies/videos/video1.mp4

index.html:1 [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000000BA313F15D0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
```

What is the correct way to add the video. Where am i going wrong. Please help

Comment: @ngokevin, could you please help me on this

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and just managed to get it work in Chrome with something like this:

```
// Create a new asset
var new_asset = document.createElement('video');
new_asset.setAttribute('id', 'dynVid'); // Create a unique id for asset
new_asset.setAttribute('src', videoUrl);

// Append the new video to the a-assets, where a-assets id="assets-id"
document.getElementById('assets-id').appendChild(new_asset);

// Add the asset to the a-video
screen.setAttribute('src', '#dynVid');
// Start playback
new_asset.play();
```

This has the added benefit that you can control playback if necessary (new_asset.pause(), new_asset.currentTime = X, muted = true, etc).

For larger videos, you may need to add some callbacks, like oncanplaythrough, to wait until the video has loaded enough.

Answer (score 0):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/guides/using-javascript-and-dom-apis.html#creating-an-entity-with-createelement

```
var videoEl = document.createElement('a-video');
videoEl.setAttribute('src', videoUrl);
this.el.appendChild(videoEl);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My code is working well in firefox but in chromium , videos were not working.

Comment: as mentioned before, the videos are getting played only in firefix and not in chrome. Also is there any way by which we can play and stop the video on button click. ?Please help